# How to embed a math expression in a text?

Tags: plotting, syntax

```
LayeredGraphPlot[{{"Subscript[X,0]" -> "m", 
   1}, {"Subscript[X,0]" -> "...", 1}, {"Subscript[X,0]" -> "n", 
   1}, {"m" -> "j", 2}, {"..." -> "j", 2}, {"n" -> "j", 2}}, 
 DirectedEdges -> True, VertexLabeling -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}, 
 EdgeRenderingFunction -> (Switch[#3, 2, {Dashed, Arrow[#1, .1]}, 
     1, {Arrow[#1, .1]}] &)]
```

The above code generates the following graph, but what I really want is $X_0$ instead of Subscript[X,0]. Is it possible to do so? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Tony, I have marked this question as "already has an answer here..." because this subject has been addressed before.  Specifically my answer demonstrates both "two dimensional" and style formatting in a *Mathematica* String.  If you find that the existing answers there do not fully answer your question please edit this question to explain what else you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
LayeredGraphPlot[{{Subscript[X, 0] -> "m", 
   1}, {Subscript[X, 0] -> "...", 1}, {Subscript[X, 0] -> "n", 
   1}, {"m" -> "j", 2}, {"..." -> "j", 2}, {"n" -> "j", 2}}, 
 DirectedEdges -> True, VertexLabeling -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}, 
 EdgeRenderingFunction -> (Switch[#3, 2, {Dashed, Arrow[#1, .1]}, 
     1, {Arrow[#1, .1]}] &)]
```